# How to Unload the Assemblies in C# dynamically

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I am trying to load and unload an assembly in my C# application, but I can't unload the assembly and can't replace that unloaded assemblies dynamically.

Comment: You are going to need to put in a lot more effort than you have done already.

Comment: How did you load the assembly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't unload an assembly.  Once it's in there it's not possible for the JIT to pull apart all the code it's compiled.

You can load it into a separate AppDomain, however, and tear down that AppDomain when you're done.

Comment: Perhaps a mention to Addin Framework would be great!

Comment: Well yes, perhaps - but then that would perhaps be putting in a bit more effort than was put into the question :)

Comment: Ya I already tried creating AppDomain. But It didn't help me. Thanks Andras.

Comment: Ya I already tried creating AppDomain. But It didn't help me. Thanks Andras